# How to draw a stickman with turtle graphics in Python idle?

Tags: windows

I am not trying to make a game, just a drawing. However I am not sure how to proceed.

I'm using this article: https://lti.flvsgl.com/flvs-cat-content/jviqsic79osifb0qmtbb1dhea2/flvs-cat-session/educator_foundofprog_v18_gs/global/interactives/python_idle/python_idle.htm

My code so far is:

```
# Writing Functions

import turtle

def main():

    jim = turtle.turtle()
    jim.speed(10)
    
    #draw a stickman
    
    # move to position
    
    jim.setpos(0, -20)
    
    jim.left(90)
    
    # draw body
    jim.color("black")
    jim.forward(60)
    
    # draw head
    jim.color("black")
    jim.forward(90)
    jim.circle(45)
    
    # move to position
    jim.penup()
    jim.setpos(20, -20) #Sets the position of the turtle
    jim.left(90)
    jim.pendown()
    
main()
```

but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: The link you have supplied is probably tied to your IP address - I get a 403 session error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import turtle

def main():

  jim = turtle.Turtle() #Remember the capital T
  jim.speed(0) #A speed of 0 makes him go as fast as possible

  arm_length = 100 #Change these if you want
  leg_length = 120

  def reset(): #reset sends him back to the center
    jim.pu() #pu is short for penup. Either work, you can use them interchangeably
    jim.setpos(0,0)
    jim.pd() #pd is short for pendown


  #draw a stickman

  reset()

  #head
  jim.seth(90) #seth is short for set_heading, and it changes the direction jim is facing.
  jim.fd(30)
  jim.rt(90)
  jim.circle(50)

  reset()

  #arm 1
  jim.seth(160)
  jim.fd(arm_length/2)
  jim.rt(20)
  jim.fd(arm_length/2)

  reset()

  #arm 2
  jim.seth(20)
  jim.fd(arm_length/2)
  jim.lt(20)
  jim.fd(arm_length/2)

  reset()

  #leg 1
  jim.seth(270)
  jim.fd(50)
  jim.seth(230)
  jim.fd(leg_length/2)
  jim.lt(40)
  jim.fd(leg_length/2)

  reset()

  #leg 2
  jim.seth(270)
  jim.fd(50)
  jim.seth(310)
  jim.fd(leg_length/2)
  jim.rt(40)
  jim.fd(leg_length/2)

main()
```